# Python. Не могу понять в чем проблема.Код очень прост,который должен запоминать имя пользователя,но когда запускаю,то ругается

Tags: python, json

```
from json import load, dump
filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        user = load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    user = input('What is your name? ')
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        dump(user, f)
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {user}!")
else:
    print(f"Welcome back, {user}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где текст самой ошибки, зачем вы его обрезали? В какой кодировке у вас записан файл `'username.json'`, в такой кодировке его нужно и открывать как файл. Видимо, у вас кодировка не совпадает.

Comment: Кодировка по классике - utf-8.Вот сам текст ошибки.Не понимаю еще и то,почему указываются строки,которых у меня даже нет

Comment: Вот и попробуйте указать `open(filename, encoding='utf-8')`. Поскольку у вас `Windows`, то вполне может быть, что файлы питоном по умолчанию читаются в `cp1251`. Ну либо всё-таки файл не в `utf-8`, а наоборот в `cp1251`, я бы попробовал разные варианты.

Comment: И это не может быть текст ошибки - самой ошибки на скриншоте нет. Строки которых у вас нет - потому что ошибка произошла внутри библиотеки, которую вызвал ваш код и показаны строки этой библиотеки. Но саму собственно ошибку вы почему-то отрезали из скриншота.

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: CrazyElf, уже пытался,не работает

Comment: Попробуйте поставить перед этой строкой которая даёт ошибку `print(f.read())` и посмотрите, что выведется. Нужно сначала добиться, чтобы была правильная кодировка при чтении файла.

Comment: И "не работает" - это ноль информации. Та же самая ошибка когда кодировку меняете при чтении или другая?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        user = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    user = input('What is your name? ')
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(user, f)
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {user}!")
else:
    print(f"Welcome back, {user}")
```